# How to validate some model attributes later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, devise, rails-activerecord

I have a `User` model created by `Devise` and after being created, I added some extra attributes: `username, age, year, gender` with my own validations...

**The thing is I want one page to register yourself as a user where asks you for a username, email and password.**

And once you've registered, there is a page `Profile` where you can complete the rest of the information.  It will have for example, your `telephone number`, and `first name`. You can put it or not. But in case you put something, it will validate. If it is empty, no edition on that attribute of the model will be performed, and **NO VALIDATION** will then be performed.

Both pages are treating the same Model but will add information in different moments.

The problem comes when you try to register a user in the registration page. Rails will complain because the other attributes I didn't provide are being validated by the model (when I do not want the model to validate them, at least for that page).

How can I decide what is validated each moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's always optional to add them then you can do conditional validation

```
validates :first_name, presence: true, if: :first_name?
```

If you only want to validate them after creation you can use on

```
validates :first_name, presence: true, on: :update
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Very easy and effective.

Comment: The first line does nothing as it's a tautology; confirm the presence of `:first_name` if it doesn't equal nil, but if it doesn't equal nil, then it has a value already! The second line is not working for `belongs_to` relations.

Comment: Use `belongs_to :other_model, optional: true` also for relations.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should remove all the validations for the fields present in your profile page. 
You can call a method from the model before saving the details on your profile page in the User model.
That method will check the validations required for those fields.

Comment: Ok, that might a solution, but would be very dirty because the rails way is placing validations insidee the model. Thanks for the reply though.